# Gitlab Post/Put in Node with Axios or Curl Request - Unable to write resource - 400 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, gitlab, axios

When using the Gitlab api, I cannot seem to get anything to post unless its of `"Content-Type": "text/plain"`. I have tried a curl request as well, I can use GET, but also no luck with POST/PUT.

I went through and made sure I opened access to as public as possible, checked there was a public key, etc. still no luck.

**Works**

```
let url = window.djConfig.DJ_URL + "api/v1/git" + "/project/directory";
 axios.put(url, 'stuff',{
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "text/plain"
   }
  })
  .then(function (res) {
    //do success stuff
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    //do error stuff
 })

curl --request GET --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: ycEKE_uSQiRXzMtrZuZU' 'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/git/journey-content/bower%2Ejson?ref=master'
```

But if I try to do anything a bit more robust like adding a commit message I get the error:

```
{"message":"Unable to write resource.","status":400}
```

I have my more robust Axios set up as such

**Doesn't work**

```
let url = window.djConfig.DJ_URL + "api/v1/git" + "/project/directory";
let commit = {
  file_path: 'project/directory',
  branch: 'master',
  content: '{key: "value"}',
  commit_message: 'test commit'
}

axios.put(url, commit,{
   headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
   }
})
.then(function (res) {
   // do success stuff
})
.catch(function (err) {
  // do error stuff
})


curl --request POST --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: ycEKE_uSQiRXzMtrZuZU' 'http://localhost:8911/developerjourney/api/v1/git/journey-content/projectrb%2E?branch=master&author_email=author%40example.com&author_name=Firstname%20Lastname&content=some%20content&commit_message=create%20a%20new%20file'
```

I like how Gitlab provides this useless piece of information...

> If the commit fails for any reason we return a 400 error with a
>   non-specific error message. Possible causes for a failed commit
>   include:
>
> the file_path contained /../ (attempted directory traversal); the new
>   file contents were identical to the current file contents, i.e. the
>   user tried to make an empty commit; the branch was updated by a Git
>   push while the file edit was in progress. Currently gitlab-shell has a
>   boolean return code, preventing GitLab from specifying the error.

Not sure what I am missing, but its feeling like permissions issue if I can get but not post/put.

**update**
Here is the full out put from the terminal if I make the request with --verbose

```
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8911 (#0)
> POST /developerjourney/api/v1/git/journey-content/projectrb%2E?branch=master&author_email=author%40example.com&author_name=Firstname%20Lastname&content=some%20content&commit_message=create%20a%20new%20file HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8911
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> PRIVATE-TOKEN: ycEKE_uSQiRXzMtrZuZU
> 
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< X-Powered-By: Express
< X-DJ-Redirect-URL: http://localhost:8911/developerjourney/authenticate
< X-DJ-GitLab-Host: https://localhost:30443
< X-DJ-GitLab-Path: 
< X-DJ-GitLab-Application-Id: 513ce27b4c730d461fa68ceae3eab23f726dc975c3d250de79af8d301f74f4f7
< X-DJ-JourneyGroup: journeys
< X-DJ-URL: http://localhost:8911/developerjourney/
< Set-Cookie: dj-session=18245958cb989b009e7417d76b62331a; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 05 Jan 2018 19:46:56 GMT; HttpOnly
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 52
< ETag: W/"34-mpqGlVzme26p5gWU36ILGyMDScQ"
< Date: Fri, 22 Dec 2017 19:46:56 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"message":"Unable to write resource.","status":400}
```

**using v4 api**

If you use the following snippet

```
curl --request POST --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK' 'http://localhost:8911/developerjourney/api/v4/projects/2/journey-content/app%2Fprojectrb%2E?branch=master&content=some%20content&commit_message=create%20a%20new%20file'
```

I get error text returned inside HTML. "journey-content" is my project name which is inside a group called "journeys"

Comment: Share your code of what you've done.

Comment: @cgTag hopefully thats helpful - I have added how it is being implemented.

Comment: What happens if you use `curl`? I think you should post both your request and response headers.

Comment: @JPSilvashy - header images have been added to post

Comment: It looks like you have a few issues here. I think the best approach to figuring this out would be to make sure you can interface with the Gitlab API via your command-line first, then build it in node.

It looks like the images you posted are the headers for your API, but can you post the request and response headers from the Gitlab request?

Comment: @JPSilvashy So this seems to be an issue if I try to push anything that isn't the ContentType of plain/text . So I will be rewording everything for now.

Comment: You mention that put doesn't work, but under working it is a put?  Is this a mistake, should that read as GET?  Also, the POST doesn't provide any post data, everything is in the querystring... does gitlab expect this?  Finally, can you get logs from gitlab, perhaps it has more information about why it is returning a 400.

Comment: @tswaters put works if I send everything as plain text, but not as JSON or form data. I will see if I can find the logs, this is pretty new territory for me as it is running on a docker instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is not using the correct APIs. First you need to use `/projects` api to get the project id

```
let url = window.djConfig.DJ_URL + "api/v4/" + "projects?owned=true";
```

Then above will give you something like below

```
[
    {
        "id": XXXXX,
        "description": "",
        "name": "testapi",
        "name_with_namespace": "XXXX / testapi",
        "path": "testapi",
        "path_with_namespace": "XXX/testapi",
        "created_at": "2017-12-24T19:09:11.192Z",
        "default_branch": null,
        "tag_list": [],
        "ssh_url_to_repo": "git@gitlab.com:xxx/testapi.git",
        "http_url_to_repo": "https://gitlab.com/xxx/testapi.git",
```

You need to capture the ID from this for making the next request

```
let url = window.djConfig.DJ_URL + "api/v4" + "/projects/<id>/repository/commits";
```

And you need to post the data in below format

```
{
  "branch": "master",
  "commit_message": "some commit message",
  "actions": [
    {
      "action": "create",
      "file_path": "foo/bar",
      "content": "some content"
    }
  ]
}
```

It will return below a JSON response

```
[
    {
        "id": "cbf63f8050ed033565e28f8d62288d9f6a8be1a7",
        "short_id": "cbf63f80",
        "title": "Add new file",
        "created_at": "2017-12-24T19:23:34.000+00:00",
        "parent_ids": [],
        "message": "Add new file",
        "author_name": "xxx xxx",
        "author_email": "xxx@xxx.com",
        "authored_date": "2017-12-24T19:23:34.000+00:00",
        "committer_name": "xxx xxx",
        "committer_email": "xxx@xxxx.com",
        "committed_date": "2017-12-24T19:23:34.000+00:00"
    }
]
```

You can even post using query params

```
curl --request POST --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK' 'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/13083/repository/files/app%2Fprojectrb%2E?branch=master&author_email=author%40example.com&author_name=Firstname%20Lastname&content=some%20content&commit_message=create%20a%20new%20file'
```

So your main issue is not using the project id in your urls

Comment: That makes sense, I do not know why the documentation doesn't provide a pre explanation on that. Great I'll give it a test tomorrow!

Comment: I have been trying to get it to work, I seem to be getting a 500 error with both axios and curl.  With curl I did the following

When I use 'projects/:id', I get the 500 error. I am assuming maybe this has to do with the version of the api I am using? which is v1.

Comment: You need to use v4

Comment: Using v4 and your example I get returned error text inside HTML.  See my question for updated info.

Comment: So I was able to make the calls correctly to Gitlab.com, I am now under the impression this has to do with the communication between the node app and docker instance of gitlab.

Comment: I had tested with gitlab only. But I assume hosted one should also be similar

Comment: I am going to go with your answer since you are correct, as soon as I figure out how to get past the 401 unauthorized error. Trying to pass my private token, doesn't seem to work.